# R resetting a cumsum to zero at the start of each year

Tags: r, plyr

I have a `dataframe` with a bunch of donations data.  I take the data and arrange it in time order from oldest to most recent gifts.  Next I add a column containing a cumulative sum of the gifts over time.  The data has multiple years of data and I was looking for a good way to reset the `cumsum` to 0 at the start of each year (the year starts and ends July 1st for fiscal purposes).

This is how it currently is:

```
id        date          giftamt      cumsum()
005       01-05-2001     20.00        20.00
007       06-05-2001     25.00        45.00
009       12-05-2001     20.00        65.00
012       02-05-2002     30.00        95.00
015       08-05-2002     50.00       145.00
025       12-05-2002     25.00       170.00
...          ...          ...         ...
```

this is how I would like it to look:

```
id        date          giftamt      cumsum()
005       01-05-2001     20.00        20.00
007       06-05-2001     25.00        45.00
009       12-05-2001     20.00        20.00
012       02-05-2002     30.00        50.00
015       08-05-2002     50.00        50.00
025       12-05-2002     25.00        75.00
...          ...          ...          ...
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

Here's the code that finally worked courtesy of Seb :

```
#tweak for changing the calendar year to fiscal year
df$year <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(df$giftdate), format="%Y"))
df$month <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(df$giftdate), format="%m"))
df$year <- ifelse(df$month<=6, df$year, df$year+1)

#cum-summing :)
library(plyr)
finalDf <- ddply(df, .(year), summarize, cumsum(as.numeric(as.character(giftamt))))
```

Comment: Should your example output be a little different or did you want the sum to reset on 12-05-2001?

Comment: reset is on July 1st.  Sorry for sparseness of data.

Comment: i oversaw this in my initial answer - sorry. my new attempt should work now. i think...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i would try it this way (df being the dataframe):

```
#tweak for changing the calendar year to fiscal year
df$year <- format(as.Date(df$date), format="%Y")
df$month <- format(as.Date(df$date), format="%m")
df$year <- ifelse(df$month<=6, year, year+1)

#cum-summing :)
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(year), summarize, cumsum(giftamt))
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two tasks: create a column in the data frame representing each year, then split the data, apply the cumsum, and recombine.  R has lots ways of doing both parts.

Probably the most readable way of dong the first task is with `year` from the `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)
df$year <- year(df$date)
```

Note that R has lots of date formats, so it's worth checking to see whether you are currently using `POSIXct` or `Date` or `chron` or `zoo` or `xts` or one of the other formats.

Seb's choice or `ddply` for the second task is the one I'd recommend.  For completeness, you can also use `tapply` or `aggregate`.

```
with(df, tapply(giftamt, year, cumsum))
aggregate(giftamt ~ year, df, cumsum)
```

---

With the new info that you want years to change on 1st July, update the year column to

```
df$year <- with(df, year(date) + (month(date) >= 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gifts <- read.table("gifts.txt", header=T, quote="\"")
NbGifts <- nrow(gifts)

# Determination of the relevant fiscal year ending dates
CalYear <- as.numeric(substr(gifts$date,7,10)) # calendar years
TCY <- as.numeric(names(table(CalYear))) # list of calendar years
MDFY <- "07-01-" # ending date for the current fiscal year
EFY <- paste(MDFY,TCY,sep="") # list of fiscal year ending dates
EFYplus <- cbind(TCY,EFY) # table of fiscal year ending dates
colnames(EFYplus) <- c("CalYear","EndDate")

# Manipulation of data frames in order to match
# the fiscal year end dates to the relevant dates
giftsPlusYear <- data.frame(CalYear, gifts, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
giftsPlusEFY <- merge(giftsPlusYear,EFYplus) # using the CalYear

# Date comparison in order to associate a gift to its fiscal year
DateGift <- as.Date(giftsPlusEFY$date,"%m-%d-%y") # date conversion for comparison
DateEFY <- as.Date(giftsPlusEFY$EndDate,"%m-%d-%y")
FiscYear <- ifelse(DateGift<DateEFY,giftsPlusEFY$CalYear,giftsPlusEFY$CalYear+1)

# Computation of cumulative totals per fiscal year
LastFY <- 0
CumGift <- rep(0,NbGifts)
for (g in 1:NbGifts){
  if (LastFY==FiscYear[g]){
    CumGift[g] <- CumGift[g-1] + gifts$giftamt[g]
    } else {
      CumGift[g] <- gifts$giftamt[g]
      LastFY <- FiscYear[g]
    }
}
(CumGifts <- cbind(gifts,CumGift))
```